# Diophantine Equations (another)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following equation

$756x+630y = 2394$

and i am trying to find the general solution to it. I have done these type of questions numerous times and had no difficulty but I cant seem to do this.

What I have so far is

$756x+630y=2394$

$756-1(630)=126$

$630-5(126)=0$

I tried using the technique roll back but it dosent work.

Comment: The usual method is to apply the extended Euclidean algorithm to $756$ and $630$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your calculation shows is that $126$ is the greatest common divisor of $756$ and $630$ and that $756-630=126$ and $6\times630-5\times756=0$. Since $2394/126=19$ is not fractional, we can solve the equation. $19(756-630)+k(6\times630-5\times756)=2394$.

Note that $6\times630-5\times756=0$ comes from substituting $756-630=126$ into $630-5\times126=0$.

Comment: 5×630−4×756=126 and  6×630−5×756=0 sorry im not sure where you are getting these. I can see they are right and i was wondering where they came from

Comment: Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Note that this is basically the extended Euclidean algorithm, which solves this in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide all by $$126$$ and you have to solve $$6x+5y=19$$
and then you can write $$y=4-x-\frac{1+x}{5}$$
Substitute $$\frac{1+x}{5}=t$$ we get $$x=5t-1,y=5-6t$$

Comment: This is the solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

If x= 1 and y= 1 then 6x+ 5y= 1.  So if x= 19 and y= -19, 6x+ 5y= 19.  But x= 19- 5k, y= -19+ 6k is also a solution:  6(19- 5k)+ 5(-19+ 6k)= 6(19)- 6(5)k- 5(19)+ 5(6)k= 114-95= 19 for all k.